# R: How to fix table's column width using flextable() package?

Tags: r, flextable, rhandsontable

I have two tables. First columns of both of them should have fixed width, say, 1,5 inches.
Below there is a sample script where for the table named `df1` I used flextable() function and for the table named `df2` I used flextable() and width() function. However, desired columns' width is not getting fixed to the given length, i.e. 1,5 inches.

Can someone show me how to get column width fixed?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(flextable)

df1 = data.table(
    "Сolumn1"= as.character(),
    "Column2"= as.numeric(),
    "Сolumn3"= as.character()
)

flextable(
  df1,
  col_keys = names(df1),
  cwidth = 0.75,
  cheight = 0.25
)

qflextable(df1)

df2 = data.table(
    "Сolumn1"= as.character(),
    "Column2"= as.numeric(),
    "Сolumn3"= as.character()
)

df2 <- flextable(head(df2))
df2 <- width(df2, width = 1.5)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Assets"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Current assets",
      tabName = "CurrentAssets",
      menuSubItem("Inventory", tabName = "inventory")
      )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "inventory",
        column(
          width = 7,
          "df1",
          rHandsontableOutput("Table1")  
        ),
        column(
          width = 7,
          "df2",
          rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(df1, stretcH="all")
  })

  output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(df2, stretcH="all")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with `flextable`. As is your code returns an error as you are passing a `flextable` object to `rhandsontable`. You can only have one of both. Either do you create your tables using `flextable` or using `rhandsontable`. But it's not possible to first create a `flextable` with a fixed column width and then convert it magically to a `rhandsontable`. If you want the latter then you have to set the column width using the options provided by the `rhandsontable` package.

From the [docs](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#Sizing) on sizing a `rhandsontable` you could set the column widths using the `colWidths=` argument of `hot_cols()`. Additionally, `rhandsontable()` has an argument `rowHeaderWidth` to set the width of the row names column.

Below I set the `rowHeaderWidth` to 200 and use a numeric vector to set width of the first column to 100 and to 50 for the second and third.

Note: For a column layout you have only 12 columns in total, i.e. setting the column widths to 7 for both tables will not work when you want both tables in one row. Hence, I set the width to 6 for both.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

df1 <- data.frame(
  "Сolumn1" = as.character(),
  "Column2" = as.numeric(),
  "Сolumn3" = as.character()
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  "Сolumn1" = as.character(),
  "Column2" = as.numeric(),
  "Сolumn3" = as.character()
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Assets"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Current assets",
      tabName = "CurrentAssets",
      menuSubItem("Inventory", tabName = "inventory")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "inventory",
        column(
          width = 6,
          "df1",
          rHandsontableOutput("Table1")
        ),
        column(
          width = 6,
          "df2",
          rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(df1, stretch = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 200) |> 
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(100, 50, 50))
  })

  output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(df2, stretch = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 200) |> 
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(100, 50, 50))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: dear Stefan, thanks for recreating the script. I did not know that `flextable` and `rhandsontable` are not compatible to use together.